# GArray overflow

Tags: c, glib, integer-overflow

What happens when [`g_array_append_val()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.36/glib-Arrays.html#g-array-append-val) or one of the other append/prepend functions in GLib, makes the length of the GArray larger than what guint (unsigned int) can hold?

The documentation doesn't say anything about it, so should I assume that I have to check this myself before appending (unless I know that the list will never grow beyond 65535 elements)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GArray is defined as following:

```
struct GArray {
  gchar *data;
  guint len;
};
```

So it can contain as many data as memory can hold. 
And, guint is unsigned int, which can be up to 4Gb, not 65536.

Digging deeper to GLib source, you can see, that g_array_append_val will call g_array_expand, which will later rely on g_realloc to reallocate memory. And in g_realloc sources you can see:

```
newmem = glib_mem_vtable.realloc (mem, n_bytes);
TRACE (GLIB_MEM_REALLOC((void*) newmem, (void*)mem, (unsigned int) n_bytes, 0));
if (newmem)
  return newmem;

g_error ("%s: failed to allocate %"G_GSIZE_FORMAT" bytes", G_STRLOC, n_bytes);
```

So it will fail with message 'failed to allocate %d bytes'.

Comment: Is that guaranteed by GLib? That unsigned int is at least 32 bits, and that no computer will have more memory than what unsigned int can hold?

Comment: Yes, for 32-bit architecture it will be 32 bit, and in that case each process cannot address more than 4Gb of memory. For 64 bit it would be 64 bit.

Comment: it does not need to be guaranteed by GLib: guint is just a shorthand typedef for unsigned int, and that won't ever change under the current API and ABI rules.

Comment: @potrzebie AFAIK glib does guarantee you at an at least 32bit underlying system.

Comment: Thanks for the info, though it doesn't answer my question of what happens when you overflow the len integer (=overflowing the memory) when appending vals. Will GLib terminate the program with an error message, or wrap the len integer around and behave crazy?

Comment: It will fail to allocate memory before len will overflow, and application most likely will crash with 'out of memory' or similar message.